# startsWith() not working properly with '§' character

Tags: java, string, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
String checkMessage = Arrays.stream(event.message.getFormattedText().split(" ")).filter(word -> !word.startsWith("§") || word.startsWith("§f")).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(checkMessage);
```

Unfortunately with some testing, it appears the string contains words starting with '§' but not "§f" in the output.

```
§r§928 §r§r§c§lTITAN §r§eSimplyAnon§r §ftest§r
```

How does this happen?

Comment: I see a word containing `§f` in the output. Are other similar words being excluded?

Comment: No words are excluded, my goal was to exclude words starting with '§' but not "§f"

Comment: Hmm, my test run works: http://ideone.com/cgQc3O

Comment: Strange, considering the getFormattedText() method gives the exact same output as what ends up being stored in the checkMessage, and is what you tested.

Comment: Solved by using the unicode string "\u00A7" over the actual symbol.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that your java source file has different charset compared to what's used by compiler. Use `javac -encoding <source_file_encoding>` during the compilation (for example, `javac -encoding utf8` if your source file is UTF-8) or save your source file using your system default encoding.